# What's the meaning when Kerr-Newman metric's mass is zero?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

[Kerr-Newman metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr%E2%80%93Newman_metric) represents the spacetime of a charged and rotating black hole. If the mass parameter is zero, this metric is still not the Minkowski spacetime. What's the meaning of a charged and rotating but massless object's spacetime?

Comment: For the non-charged metric see [problem 6 here](http://universeinproblems.com/index.php/Kerr_black_hole). The $\mu \rightarrow 0$ limit is just Minkowski spacetime in some rather eccentric coordinates. I would guess that the Kerr-Newman metric will just give the $\mu \rightarrow 0$ limit of the Reissner-Nordstrom metric.

Comment: I am very sure it will represent the electrovacuum space-time of a coulombic potential, but I don't recall the right transform from Boyer-Lindquist in the $M \to 0$ limit to recover the $M \to 0$ Reissner-Nordström. I guess $r^2 + a^2$ or $r^2 + a^2 + Q^2 $ spheroidal coordinate transform should work.

Comment: That's an interesting question. Is there a guarantee, that one can recover a trivial spacetime, at all? A point charge carries an infinite self-energy, which should give rise to some sort of non-trivial solution, even though I am afraid that it may be an unphysical one not just once, bit twice.

Comment: @CuriousOne: it's easy enough to study the zero mass Nordstrom spacetime.  I have no idea about how the central singularity behaves in that case.

Comment: Are you trying to force charge and/or spin to be nonzero even as the mass vanishes? Because you're really only supposed to have $a^2 + Q^2 < M^2$.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer: I am mostly curious because this case seems to lie at a point where we expect two theories to fail with a singularity at once. Electrodynamics fails "naively", general relativity less so. Can we learn something non-trivial by analyzing both limits at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

If you set M (the total mass equivalent including the irreducible rest mass, the rotational energy and the electrostatic field energy) to zero you would have to assign a negative sign to at least to one of the components. The relation in natural units of G=M=c=k<sub>c</sub>=1 is

$$\rm M=\sqrt{\frac{16 M_{\rm irr}^4+8 M_{\rm irr}^2 \ Q^2+Q^4}{16 M_{\rm irr}^2-4a^2}}$$

so if you set the total mass equivalent M and the irreduzible mass M<sub>irr</sub> to 0, the electric charge Q also has to be 0. If Q≠0, M<sub>irr</sub> would have a complex value. If you set everything but a to 0, there is no solution for a so setting M to zero without setting Q and a to 0 also does not give a physical solution.